# Python SysLogHandler -> syslog:logstash. facility not changed

Tags: python, logging, logstash, syslog

I trying logging with logging.handlers.SysLogHandler and sending this to logstash.

Python code:

```
import logging
from logging import handlers

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = handlers.SysLogHandler(facility=handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_AUTH)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info('go')
```

logstash conf:

```
input {
  syslog {
  }
}
output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug {}}
}
```

output logstash:

```
{
           "message" => "<38>2014-09-03 12:48:36,700 - simple_example - INFO - go\u0000",
          "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2014-09-03T12:48:36.702Z",
              "host" => "127.0.0.1",
              "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
          "priority" => 13,
          "severity" => 5,
          "facility" => 1,
    "facility_label" => "user-level",
    "severity_label" => "Notice"
}
```

But, if i change facility=handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_DAEMON
is not change output logstash:

```
{
           "message" => "<30>2014-09-03 12:51:52,307 - simple_example - INFO - go\u0000",
          "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2014-09-03T12:51:52.307Z",
              "host" => "127.0.0.1",
              "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
          "priority" => 13,
          "severity" => 5,
          "facility" => 1,
    "facility_label" => "user-level",
    "severity_label" => "Notice"
}
```

how do I change: facility, severity, priority, facility_label, severity_label ?

most likely because Python does not add this information:

```
output {
  stdout {}
}

2014-09-03T13:19:14.862+0000 127.0.0.1 <30>2014-09-03 13:19:14,860 - simple_example - INFO - go
```

but how add it?

Comment: it seems that Python makes a format which is not suitable for log stash.

This input only supports RFC3164 syslog, but "2014-09-03T13:19:14.862+0000 127.0.0.1 <30>2014-09-03 13:19:14,860 - simple_example - INFO - go" differs from the RFC3164

Answer (score 2):

> how do I change: facility, severity, priority, facility_label,
>   severity_label ?

Check out the docs for [logging.handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html):

- You can include the `facility` in the SysLogHandler initialization.  Allowed levels are listed in doc linked above:

  ```
  ch = handlers.SysLogHandler(facility=handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_AUTH, facility=LOG_LOCAL0)
  ```
- `priority` is mapped from the logging level, which is set by the message sender `logger.warn()` vs `logger.info()` etc.  Documentation for `mapPriority` states, "The default algorithm maps DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR and CRITICAL to the equivalent syslog names, and all other level names to 'warning'."